# Export sql convert datetime to yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

I am required to export data via SQL.  One of the fields needs to look like the below: (Not sure what the 'T' is).  The source field is in datetime format.

```
2019-08-15T08:30:00
```

Is there a specific datatype for this, or will I have to convert to varchar etc and concat the 'T'?  As it stands my SQL is pretty simple:

```
SELECT [Jobf_DteLog] as DateLogged,
FROM   [tblJobs]
```

Comment: that is `ISO 8601` format for date time. Refer to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . To convert to that format use `convert()` with `style 126`

Comment: @Squirrel thanks - how do I drop the 'mmm' from that though?  I only need yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS

Comment: convert to a specific length - you need 19 chars so simply `convert(char(19), Jobf_DteLog, 126)`:

Comment: specify the `varchar` size : `convert(varchar(19), Jobf_DteLog, 126)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2019-08-15T08:30:00` is the ISO 8601 date format. 
To get the desired output you can use ether [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
select format(Jobf_DteLog, 'yyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')
     , convert(varchar(30), Jobf_DteLog, 126)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7ff9449c399413573da386ce63bee6a)

Comment: Whenever possible, prefer convert over format, for performance. Read Aaron Bertrand's [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) for details.